# Firefox 35.0 and strange bug with fade on png transparent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Well i'm using the responsive plugin [ResponsiveSlides.js](http://responsiveslides.com/) and it was working properly but after this new firefox update, some problems with PNG Transparent on fade comes, someone knows if that could be a bug or not?

[image]
[image]

very strange, i make some tests like putting a background-color these PNG pics then it works fine, it sound like the old IE problems with PNG on fade ... but idk.

Live example: http://www.arquitet.us/homologacao/

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Hi, please add your code to the question, otherwise this question risks being closed.

Comment: I edited the question with a live example

Comment: @Akarienta i edited the question with a live example

Comment: It seems like a bug of transition efect, I have the same problem with Foundation tool tips and yours example doesn't work for me too in Firefox 35.

Comment: @Akarienta do u have same problem in firefox?

Comment: @StackAwalke yes, I do.

Comment: hum i'm trying to find out